# Java/Spring Boot - how to connect with server using https

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl

Full disclosure: I am still trying to understand how the whole security certificate ecosystem works. There is much I still don't have a good handle on.

I want to be able to connect/interact with a web application REST API that is using SSL/TLS (HTTPS). The server has a security certificate in its trust store that presumably it will provide when my app attempts to establish a secure connection. To my knowledge, there is no need for mutual authentication. I don't know if this is helpful, but the certificate was created and signed by an intermediate CA.

My application is written in the Java language and utilizes Spring Boot for the many features and capabilties that framework provides. Initially to keep things simple, my code consists of a very simple server and client.

I'm trying to understand what needs to be done for secured HTTPS communications to occur between these two apps, specifically with the certificate I have described. What I have found so far seems to involve the JDK keytool utility, but I'm not sure in what way I need to use it - or even if it needs to be involved. I don't know what security "data" I may need to provide in this process, or in what form it may need to be in. I am also unsure what needs to be done in software to make this all work correctly.

**Note**: The settings in the `application.yaml` files reflects what I tried to use from a source on the Internet (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-secure-https-service). I could not get that to work.

Here is the simple server and client application code.

**Server**:

ServerApp.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServerApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

WelcomeController.java:

```
@RestController
public class WelcomeController {
  @GetMapping(value = "/welcome")
  public String welcome() {
    return "Welcome To Secured REST Service";
  }
}
```

application.yaml:

```
---
server:
  port: 8443
  servlet:
    context-path: /
  ssl:
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: classpath:keystore/<cert file>
    key-store-password: <password>
    key-alias: <alias>
```

**Client**:

ClientApp.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ClientApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ClientApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

ClientController.java:

```
@RestController
public class ClientController {
  private static final String WELCOME_URL = "https://localhost:8443/welcome";

  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate        restTemplate;

  @GetMapping("/welcomeclient")
  public String greetMessage() {
    String response = restTemplate.getForObject(WELCOME_URL, String.class);
    return response;
  }
}
```

CustomRestTemplateConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomRestTemplateConfiguration {
  @Value("${trust.store}")
  private Resource trustStore;

  @Value("${trust.password}")
  private String   trustStorePassword;

  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
      CertificateException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
        .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore.getURL(), trustStorePassword.toCharArray())
        .build();
    
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConFactory)
        .build();
    
    ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
  }
}
```

application.yaml:

```
---
server:
  port: 8082

trust:
  store: classpath:keystore/<cert file>
  password: <password>
```

Comment: In real-world scenario, TLS is typically handled by an external proxy / API Gateway, rather than within server code itself. Client certificates will still be needed, however. But, is your question about the server or the client? You can find plenty of public HTTPS APIs available to use for a client.

Comment: I'm referring to the client. The server will be a much more complex application (Prometheus) that I will attempt to make RESTful calls to.

Comment: Okay, I was confused on `server.port: 8082` if you don't have two servers, then

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't quite get the point of port 8082. Why not use 80 or 8080? In this instance, I guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: You can disable the SpringBoot server if you only want to use Boot Configuration for a client application. In any case, do you get a specific error when you try to make requests to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple terms, a party (client or server) will trust another party (server or client) if the other party’s certificate chain as provided on the wire can be traced back (recursively via signers) to the CACERTS stored in the original party’s JRE. (or is in the original party’s truststore)

It is fairly unusual to use mutually authenticated TLS so client side certificates are rare. In most cases authentication of a client is done with user credentials, api keys, etc. Anyway, it looks like you have the client cert setup correctly.

If the server certificate is signed by a Intermediate CA that has a cert held in the client’s CACERTS then no client side intervention is necessary. On the server a keychain from a CACERTS cert down to the server cert needs to be configured via application.yaml, as you correctly show in your question.

If the Intermediate CA’s signing cert is not registered in the official Java CACERTS in the client’s JRE then it must be added like [this](https://learn.capstorm.com/copystorm/frequently-asked-questions/installation/help-i-am-getting-a-certificate-error-pkix-path/#:%7E:text=This%20type%20of%20error%20typically,trusted%20store%20file%20%E2%80%9Ccacerts%E2%80%9D.). I find it easier to add untrusted Intermediate CA certs to CACERTS rather than adding the server cert to the client truststore (as you correctly show) because that allows multiple servers to be trusted (because, in a typical corporate environment, they will all have certs signed by the Intermediate CA)

If a client can’t build a trusted cert chain to the cert provided by a server an SSL connection will fail with the dreaded “PKIX path building failed” error.

I find it helpful to load a server GET path (eg `/welcome`) in a browser to get a look at what cert the server is passing back.

Comment: Regarding your statement about adding the cert to the *client* trust store (or, rather your suggestion to *not* add it), am I doing that with the code provided? Do I need to do that? I'm still not sure what steps need to occur on the client side.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that the intermediate cert will not be found in the JRE cert store, so I will need to have it added on the server side. Do I need to have it added to the JRE on the client side as well? Will look into the link you provided. *If the server certificate is signed by a Intermediate CA that has a cert held the client’s CACERTS then no client side intervention is necessary.* - Nothing at all?

Comment: After some more experimentation, there's something I don't understand about the code above (keep in mind this was modelled on this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-secure-https-service). Why is the certificate file used on **both** sides? My guess is for the purpose of the demo - to avoid having to install it in the JRE trust store. But, then the `RestTemplate` config wouldn't work, since it needs these items. My confusion worsens.

Comment: "no client side intervention is necessary. - Nothing at all?" Yes, if a server cert is signed by a proper CA (like AWS, Google, LetsEncrypt or any others that want to expose secure SSL) then the client will trust the server without further intervention.

Comment: "Why is the certificate file used on both sides?" - because 1) the cert is not signed by a real CA and 2) that example uses the trustStore config rather than adding to CACERTS. It is installed on the server (with the private key) to provide SSL and it is installed on the client to 'tell' the client to trust that particular certificate. Common name and SAN on the server cert must  also match the server's hostname - that's what it is there to attest to.

Comment: "I think it's fair to say that the intermediate cert will not be found in the JRE cert store, so I will need to have it added on the server side" - no on the **client** side so that the client can run up the PKIX path from the server certificate to a cert in CACERTS. The server does not have to be told to trust its own cert.

Comment: "adding the cert to the client trust store" - you are already doing it with client application.yaml trust. store=classpath:keystore/<cert file>